# Zune same features as WP7? (gesture, accelerometer)

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

We don't have zune HD in Canada (yet) just wondering if it has the same programmable features as WP7? Like gestures and accelerometer.

Basically if I am just making a game, with screen controls (thumbsticks on the screen) is this an easy port to zune?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with the WP7 API as I should be but I've done some Zune XNA programming and you have access to the touchscreen and accelerometer fairly straightforwardly. I can safely assume a port between the two would be relatively painless.

You get a list of `TouchLocation`s from XInput and you can do what you will with them.  Each touch has an ID that allows you to identify drags/swipes.

The Accelerometer just gives you a 3D vector showing the current acceleration (with 0,-1,0 being the norm due to gravity). This [tutorial](http://www.abstrys.com/2010/02/making-the-zune-hd-sparkle-with-xna-game-studio-3-1-part-1/) gives a good example of using the Zune's interface.

Comment: thank you, I basically want to prototype a game without actually using the WP7 (can't get my hands on it where I live, but I could get a zune HD)

Comment: But ZuneHD and WP7 are not the same like iPhone and iPod Touch are. ZuneHD's APIs are a subset of XNA 3. XNA 4 is used for programming WP7 and XNA 4 doesn't even support Zune programming any more. Probably in the future they'll release a Zune that runs the same software as WP7, but right now I wouldn't touch the thing.